# What means verb 擾敵?

Tags: cantonese

This is [Episode 603](https://www.dandanzan.com/zongyi/33121.html) of TVB's 後生仔傾吓偈. Here's context. 她 is Rosita Kwok, who cooked many desserts and foods for other contestants.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

擾：(v.) To disturb (打擾) or interfere (干擾)

敵：(n.) The enemy.

Literally it means to disturb the enemy.

However when the two words are put together the meaning is closer to "misdirect/undermine".

Answer (score 2):

擾敵 is short for 騷擾敵人 (disturb; harass the enemy)

It is borrowed from military strategy and tactics term --  *When the enemy is at rest, **disturb** him* (to weaken him)

Other military strategy and tactics terms used in general conversation:

誘敵 short for 引誘敵人 (lure the enemy) - *When you want the enemy to attack, lure him* (into a trap)

欺敵 short for 欺騙敵人 (deceive the enemy)- *use deception to mislead the enemy* (to make wrong decision)